# Escape single quotes from comma separated string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I am trying to escape single quotes from the comma separated string in Oracle SQL Developer, below is my `Select` query:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN PS.SUPPLIER_NO IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END) AS "Check"
      ,dm."branch_id", dm."SUPPLIER_NO", dm."supplier_name", dm."date_created"
      ,dm."vendor_no", dm."ORDERING_ADDRESS_1", dm."ORDERING_ADDRESS_2"
      ,dm."ORDERING_CITY", dm."ORDERING_STATE_COD", dm."ORDERING_ZIP"
      ,dm."country_code", dm."fax_area_code", dm."fax_no", dm."fax_extension"
FROM datamart.udm_supplier_dim@teradata.wesco.com dm
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_SUPPLIERS PS ON PS.SUPPLIER_NO = dm."SUPPLIER_NO"
 AND PS.BRANCH_ID = dm."branch_id"
 AND PS.PROJECT_ID = 'e82a654af6c64e8297576b88b5eff138'
WHERE dm."branch_id" IN (REPLACE('6218, 5577','''',''''''));
```

I tried to replace/escape the single quotes from `Where IN` clause but it gives error of invalid number.

> ORA-01722: invalid number

When I am trying to select same string using replace from other select statement it is working.

```
select REPLACE('6218, 5577','''','''''') from dual;
```

above query works as expected and gives o/p as `'6218, 5577'`.

Can anyone please advise, Why it is not working in my main Select statement?

Comment: in your string is no single quotes. you query Returns a string `6218, 5577`and not a list of id's. you should parse your string

Comment: it is a string which we are passing to the parameter from application to oracle sql developer procedure, for understanding i write the example string here in select query `i.e. '6218, 5577'`.

Comment: Can your application be changed to pass a collection of numbers, instead of a single string value - which it has presumably generated from a list anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'6218, 5577'` this is a string and not a list of values. So if you do `select REPLACE('6218, 5577','''','''''') from dual;` you are trying to replace single Quote in your string. since it does not exists in your string, nothing will be replaced.

the result of you select is still the same string  and not a list as you expect.

you should split a comma delimited string in rows.

here is one way to do that

```
with tab as (
  SELECT trim(regexp_substr('6218, 5577', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
   FROM dual
   CONNECT BY instr('6218, 5577', ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
)
```

than you can use it on your select

```
with tab as (
  SELECT trim(regexp_substr('6218, 5577', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
   FROM dual
   CONNECT BY instr('6218, 5577', ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
) 
select ...
  from ...
  WHERE dm."branch_id" IN (select str from tab );
```